# Opencart dont redirect not found links

Tags: .htaccess, opencart

I migrated my e-commerce site oscommerce to open-cart and my old links coming to the open-cart site. whenever old links requested open-cart redirects to the homepage if the pattern is like this .../index.php?manufacturers_id=...

I changed .htacess file to exclude redirect to the homepage by defining these lines

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} manufacturers_id
RewriteRule .* NOT.php
```

if requested url contains manufacturers_id "it will" redirect to NOT.php instead homepage. But these .htaccess definitions don't work

I also want to cancel 404 pages I prefer to use the server default error page.

How can I make this? Thank you

Comment: Can you give an example of an old URL and a new one?

Comment: I solved this problem by checking all reqest url, if it contains old site url patterns i redirect it not existed page so opencart redirects to 404. with this way google knows crawl requested page is not exist